# Mysql stored Procedure syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL Stored Procedure. It is like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
SET @x = 1;
REPEAT

INSERT INTO `edittables` (`USER_ID`, `REFERENCETYPE`, `COLUMNNAME`, `VERSION`, `CREATEDDATETIME`, `LASTUPDATEDDATETIME`) VALUES
  (@x ,12,'type', 0, "2014-08-12 00:00:00", "2000-08-12 00:00:00");

SET @x = @x + 1;
UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END
//
```

I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPEAT

INSERT INTO `edittables` (`USER_ID`, `REFERENCETYPE`, `COLUMNNAM' at line 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: One user solved this issue but unfortunately he deleted his post. I wanted to make that as an answer. He recommended me that change @x to X and it works! Thanks him!

Comment: @user3833823 Have you solved your problem with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELIMITER //   
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INTEGER;
    SET x = 1;
    REPEAT
         INSERT INTO `edittables` (`USER_ID`, `REFERENCETYPE`, `COLUMNNAME`,`VERSION`, `CREATEDDATETIME`, `LASTUPDATEDDATETIME`) VALUES (X ,12,'type', 0, "2014-08-12 00:00:00", "2000-08-12 00:00:00");
         SET  x = x + 1;
    UNTIL x > p1
    END REPEAT;    
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: My insert doesn't have issue because I tested it separately.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar yes, I did